# Storing file of Char and Int

Tags: c

I have no idea why I can't figure this out, but I'm trying to read a file that looks like this

```
000xx
11xx0
0x1x0
11110
```

I'm trying to read the file,then search the for the "x" values and replace them with "2" then store them in an array for later use. The output should look like this.

```
00022
11220
02120
11110
```

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right, I figured I had to store the file into an array, then search and replace. Here is my code for just reading the file and attempting to print, I tried using both int arrays and char arrays, I don't know why I can't figure this out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int main()
{

FILE *fvec;
fvec =fopen("numbers.vec" , "r");
if(!fvec){printf("error reading file");}  
int col, row;
  int array[10][10];

  for (col = 0; col < 10; ++col){
    for (row = 0; row <10; ++row){
     fscanf(fvec, "%d", &array[col][row]);}
    }


  for (col = 0; col < 10; ++col){
    for (row = 0; row <10; ++row){
      printf("%d", array[col][row]);}
      printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This is what I get when printing

```
0039300480203200
48008044
183289603930048039300480
```

Comment: First of all you should check the return value of `fscanf` as it might fail. You are allocating a `10x10` array when your file might contain less bytes. I'd suggest reading your file char by char and saving in a multi dimensional char array. One you reach a `\n` start filling the next row.

Comment: `"%d"` is for integers. `x` is not an integer right? Always check the return value of `fscanf`.

Comment: The inner loop will go across, so does your columns, the the outer loop should advance downward so it does your rows.

Comment: So should I use an if statement for return of ints? Then use another if statement for return char?

Comment: Many ways to do it. My suggestion would be to read a whole line with `fgets` and then iterate over each character replacing any `x` with `2`.

Comment: I would just read everything as a char.

Comment: You're trying to read data which is a mix of digits and xes as ints. That will cause endless headaches. Read as strings / chars.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be reading a file with ASCII characters (digits and x), you should therefore convert the read char into a digit as you read them along. Secondly as you stated you need to convert character 'x' into number 2 which is straightforward. Also the terminating condition of the loop can be improved that is read only as far as the number of lines in the file or max rows (lines) in your file. Given the above you may want to do something as below

```
  memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));             // do this so that everything is set to 0
  while ((fgets(buf, 20, fvec) != 0) && ( row < 10)) {
     printf("%s", buf);
     for (int col = 0; col < strlen(buf); col++) {
          if (buf[col] == 'x') {
             array[row][col] = 2;              // turn this to digit 2
          } else if (isdigit(buf[col])) {
             array[row][col] = buf[col]  - '0';// turn this to a digit
          }
     }
     row++;
  }
```

you can also read character by character (fscanf with %c etc.) but the above to just give you an example